# scraping sitemap using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build a site map using python
here's my code (sitemap builder.py)

```
  from urllib2 import urlopen
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import datetime
  import random
  import re

   pages = set()
def getLinks (pageUrl):
global pages
html = urlopen("http://www.mysite.ch" + pageUrl )
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for link in bsOj.findAll("a" , href = re.compile("^(/f/)")):
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        if link.attrs['href'] not in pages:
                newPage = link.attrs['href']
                print(newPage)
                pages.add(newPage)
                getLinks(newPage)
   getLinks("")
```

I have the following message error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sitemap builder.py", line 19, in <module>
   getLinks("")
  File "sitemap builder.py", line 12, in getLinks
   for link in bsOj.findAll("a" , href = re.compile("/f/")):
  NameError: global name 'bsOj' is not defined
```

I 'm new in python i will appreciate any help/tip or tutorial,

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message?  `bsOj` is not defined. Change it to `BeautifulSoup` or alias it in your import statement

Comment: Slightly off topic, but please corrently indent the code you provided. Badly indented python is just trash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue with your code is in the definition of `bsobj` as global.

In Python, `global` means "module-level", and it's only used within a function for module-level names that are to be rebound within the function. It's not meant as a module-level "forward declaration" - something that doesn't exist, since when a module is loaded (executed or imported), all code at the top level is executed sequentially.

To make this work, after your `import`, define the `bsobj` with a value.

p.s. You can use a formatter for your code as it doesn't look very nice and consistent. Check `yapf` or `black` :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to correct your line:

```
for link in bsOj.findAll("a" , href = re.compile("^(/f/)")):
```

By:

```
for link in bsObj.findAll("a" , href = re.compile("^(/f/)")):
```

Comment: Thank for help but now i got:  ` codeFile "sitemap builder.py", line 12
    for link in bsObj.findAll("a",href = re.compile("^(/f/)")) :^IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level` Is it an indentation error ?

Comment: The indentation of your code isn't correct now, try to delete the spaces before your line and use tabular button of your keyboard to get correct indentation of your code.

Good luck!